# The external configuration file (js) Angular2 project , which should not be in the built js file

Tags: typescript, angular

I created an application which is on the same level as the index.html file is configuration.conf.js

This file have one line of code, with declaration of global url for all requests:

```
var urlConf = "http://192.168.1.54:58536/connect.svc/";
```

File after modifying requesty was directed to the address , but when you build the main angular js file , plays it together with all the other js files.

Despite the fact that the file is uploaded to the server , it changes it , do not change. How to make an application used the URL specified in the file connection.conf.js

The function which imports the value of the URL of the file connection.conf.js:

```
import '../../../connection.conf.js';
declare var urlConf: string;

export function url(url, urlParameters?) {

if (urlConf.slice(-1) !== '/') {
    urlConf = urlConf + '/';
}

let urlGlobal = urlConf;

if (urlGlobal && !urlParameters) {
    return `${urlGlobal}${url}`;
} else if (urlGlobal && urlParameters) {
    return `${urlGlobal}${url}${urlParameters}`;
} else {
    return undefined;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, also stuck with this. I need to reuse the same compiled angular2 artifact in different environments, loading the endpoint from external JS config file.